# DoubleClick Add TextBox on MousePosition

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a simple practice: Double click to create a textBox on mouse location (X,Y)

It is creating the object, but far from the mouse exact position.

```
private void DynamicObjects_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    this.Controls.Add(txtBox);
    txtBox.Top = MousePosition.Y;
    txtBox.Left = MousePosition.X;

    //txtBox.Location = MousePosition; --Still off away from Mouse real location
    //txtBox.Location = MousePosition.Y; -- Fives erro Cannot implicitly convert Int to 'System.Drawing.Point'
}
```

Only way I've found to short of work is using `.Top` and `.Left`.

Why is creating far from mouse?

Comment: Why aren't you using the location from the `MouseEventArgs` event object?

Comment: Maybe you want to use a ContextMenuStrip to add new Controls to a Container. You can assign this ContextMenuStrip to all Containers that are allowed to host these new Controls (this way, you don't need any very specific event handler). The `MousePosition` will then come in handy. Of course, as mentioned in the answer, you have to position this Control inside the relative bounds of its new Parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MousePosition` gets the position of mouse cursor in screen coordinates.

We have to translate it to the client coordinates.

```
var textBox = new TextBox();

textBox.Location = PointToClient(MousePosition);

Controls.Add(textBox);
```

We need to call this method from the same control that we will place the TextBox on.

For example:

```
this.PointToClient
this.Controls.Add
```

or

```
panel.PointToClient
panel.Controls.Add
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I will try this solution, and give feedback afterwards.